# Apktool not compiling APK file, no dist folder created

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I tried compiling an app with apktool by doing this command: `apktool b hw`, but no dist folder or apk is created. I don't know what the issue is, as it only gives warnings, no errors. The hw folder is decompiled by apktool.
Output:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.6.0
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/ActiveWallpaperSettings'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:1548: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/DialogWindowTitle'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:1556: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:2171: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Preference.Holo'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:2226: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/PreferenceFragment.Holo'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:2232: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/PreferenceFragmentList'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:2238: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/PreferenceHeaderList'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:3161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.TextSelectHandle'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:3656: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowSmall'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:3667: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.
W:
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:3700: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Material.Spinner.DropDown'.
W:
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_16380312480165228894185263819163371274.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 1000152553, --version-name, 10.1.2.553, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL11554412069323265251.tmp, -e, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL3205927670635186590.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res, -M, C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\AndroidManifest.xml]
W: C:\Users\User\Downloads\hw\res\values\styles.xml:3754: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.SearchView'.
W:
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that [resource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_holo.xml#355) in the AOSP master branch. So I'd recommend running `apktool empty-framework-dir` in case you have an outdated framework bundle.

This means Apktool on next run will regenerate it from the internal framework, which as of 2.6.0 is up to date.

Comment: Now there are more warnings, but still no apk: https://cl1p.net/code